# Desktop Icons Accidentally Renamed

Tags: windows-7, rename

Here's a strange issue, I hope it's on-topic.

My son (13 y/o) was using our laptop, running Windows 7, and suddenly all desktop icons where renamed to `something (1)`, `something (2)` etc. (except `My Computer` and `Recycle Bin`). All icons still work - the shortcuts point where they did before, folders contain the files - just the names are wrong.
We asked him what he did, he said that he created a file on the desktop, and named it `something`, and didn't touch any other file.

I'm not really asking about fixing it - ctrl-Z didn't help, and I'm afraid of using system restore, because I did things since then which I don't want to undo.

My question is how could it have hapenned?
I'm willing to assume that my son's report isn't 100% accurate - he may have clicked where he didn't mean to. But he certainly didn't rename the files one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a little off topic, because we don't know what happened, all we can do is supply theories. If you change you question to what can I do to fix this situation, it's on topic. I won't down-vote though.

Comment: Happens to me now and then and with W10 also: I create something on the desktop and try to rename/delete it. Somehow the selection is expanded to include all the files & folders on the desktop. The selection isn't shown until I press enter and the changes are already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the desktop icons were selected when the rename was done, it would rename all of them as you describe.

You can confirm that by creating a couple of new folders, select them both, then hit F2 to rename them - only one shows that it is being renamed at the time, but both will be renamed when you hit enter.

Comment: Sonny-boy probably created the new folder then accidently hit ctl + a, then right clicked his new folder (or f2) and selected rename.

Comment: `Sonny-boy probably created the new folder then accidently hit ctl + a, then right clicked his new folder (or f2) and selected rename.` Sounds about right; I always end up unintentionally renaming multiple items right after creating a folder because Explorer does not properly select the new folder. Worse, if it doesn’t redirect keyboard focus fast enough, you could end up pressing `Ctrl+A` (or something else) while trying to enter a filename, and end up selecting an item instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that SYSTEM RESTORE can be your friend.

Restore Points are created quite often, e.g., when Microsoft Security Essentials does its daily update.

So, launch it, and view the dates/times at which the Restore Points were created,
relative to the "other changes" that you have made, and pick the most-recent one
that precedes the "rename-all-selected-files" operation.

Note that System Restore does not touch the contents of your 'Documents' folder.
However, if you put some files/folders/shoftcuts onto your Windows Desktop, back them up,
before doing a System Restore, because it will restore an older Desktop
(with the proper names, but without your new files/folders/shortcuts).

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's indeed the only solution. But it's been a while, and I have no idea what me and my family might have changed since, so I'm not going to risk losing data. Manually renaming the files back seems safer.